# How to add another array value in codeigniter using getRecords

Tags: codeigniter

The orignial code was like this , I want to get landline_no value also in getRecords, How to do that

```
public function checklead() {
$lead = $_POST['number'];
$check =  $this->common_model->getRecords('leads',array("phone_no"=>$lead));
if(count($check) > 0) {
$lead = $this->common_model->getRecored_row('leads',array("phone_no"=>$lead));
if($lead->assignto_self != 0) {
$assignto = $lead->assignto_self;
$key = 'Self Assign';
} else if($lead->assignto_se != 0) {
$assignto = $lead->assignto_se;
$key = '';}
```

What I have achieved so far,but not getting array values from getRecords

```
$lead = $_POST['number'];
$check =  $this->common_model->getRecords('leads',array("phone_no"=>$lead),array("landline_no"=>$lead));
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($check); 
//echo  $check[0]['landline_no'];exit;
if(count($check) > 0) {
$lead = $this->common_model->getRecored_row('leads',array("phone_no"=>$lead,"landline_no"=>$check[0]['landline_no']));
```

Code for getRecords:

```
function getRecords($table,$db = array(),$select = "*",$ordercol = '',$group = '',$start='',$limit=''){
            $this->db->select($select);
            if(!empty($ordercol)){
                $this->db->order_by($ordercol);
            }
            if($limit != '' && $start !=''){
                $this->db->limit($limit,$start);
            }
            if($group != ''){
                $this->db->group_by($group);
            }
            $q=$this->db->get_where($table, $db);
            return $q->result_array();

        }



// Get Recored row
    public function getRecored_row($table,$where)
    {
        $q = $this->db->where($where)
                        ->select('*')
                     ->get($table);

        return $q->row();
    }
```

Check my answer: This code also working well, i have written, but i am not sure , this logic is correct or not kindly check this one.

```
public function checklead() {
$lead = $_POST['number'];

if($this->common_model->getRecords('leads',array("phone_no"=>$lead)))
{
$check=$this->common_model->getRecords('leads',array("phone_no"=>$lead));
}
else
{
$check=$this->common_model->getRecords('leads',array("landline_no"=>$lead));
}
echo "<pre>";
//echo $check; 
//print_r($check); exit; 
 $p= $check[0]['phone_no'];
$l= $check[0]['landline_no'];  
// exit;
if(count($p) > 0 || count($l)>0) {
$lead = $this->common_model->getRecored_row('leads',array("phone_no"=>$p));
$lead1 = $this->common_model->getRecored_row('leads',array("landline_no"=>$l));

if($lead->assignto_self != 0 || $lead1->assignto_self != 0) {
$assignto = $lead->assignto_self;
$key = 'Self Assign';
} else if($lead->assignto_se != 0 || $lead1->assignto_se != 0) {
$assignto = $lead->assignto_se;
$key = '';
}else if($lead->assignto_tl != 0 || $lead1->assignto_tl != 0) {
$assignto = $lead->assignto_tl;
$key = '';
} else if($lead->uploaded_by != 0 || $lead1->uploaded_by != 0) {
$assignto = $lead->uploaded_by;
$key = 'Uploaded by';
}

$user = $this->common_model->getRecored_row('admin',array("id"=>$assignto));
$role = $this->common_model->getRecored_row('role',array("id"=>$user->role));

$this->session->set_flashdata('message', array('message' => 'This Lead Already exist with '.$user->name.' ('.$role->role.') '.' ','class' => 'danger'));
redirect(base_url().'leads');
} else {
redirect(base_url().'leads/add_newlead/'.$lead);
}
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for `getRecords` and `getRecord_row`

Comment: I updated the code, but i dont understand the code for getReocords and getRecord_row, please explain  me that also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be any reason to use `getRecords()`. The `$check` value has no useful purpose and creating it is a waste of resources.

We don't need `$check` because `getRecord_row()` will return the "lead" if found so the only check needed is to see if `getRecord_row()` returns anything. `getRecord_row()` uses the database function `row()` which returns only one row or `null` if no rows are found. Read about `row()` [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows).

If what you want is to find the "lead" that has either a "phone_no" **or** a "landline_no" equal to `$_POST['number']` then you need to use a custom string for the where clause. (See #4 at on this [documentation page](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data).) You need a custom string because `getRecord_row()` does not allow any other way to ask for rows `where a='foo' OR b='foo'`. Here is what I think you are looking for.

```
public function checklead()
{
    // use input->post() it is the safe way to get data from $_POST
    $phone = $this->input->post('number');
    // $phone could be null if $_POST['number'] is not set
    if($phone)
    {
        $lead = $this->common_model->getRecored_row('leads', "phone_no = $phone OR landline_no = $phone");
        // $lead could be null if nothing matches where condition
        if($lead)
        {
            if($lead->assignto_self != 0)
            {
                $assignto = $lead->assignto_self;
                $key = 'Self Assign';
            }
            else if($lead->assignto_se != 0)
            {
                $assignto = $lead->assignto_se;
                $key = '';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main difference between `getRecords()` and `getRecord_row()` is the number of records (rows of data) to return. `getRecord_row()` will return a maximum of one record while `getRecords()` might return many records.

`getRecords()` accepts arguments that allow control of what data is selected (`$db`, `$select`),  how it is arranged (`$ordercol`, `$group`), and the number of rows to retrieve (`$limit`) starting at row number x (`$start`) .

Comment: DFriend you answer is correct , kindly check my answer also, now only i checked my stack account, but i strongly wanted to know this line sql query like select * from table ordercol, they have separated by , like this $select = "*",$ordercol = '',$group = '',$start='',$limit='') whether is code is matching to our logic or not,